# export plots with netlogo

Tags: csv, plot, gnuplot, netlogo

I am trying to export all the plots of my NetLogo model after simulation runs in a csv format with the primitive `export-all-plots`.
I haven't found yet the way to open this csv file with an external reader in order to get more clear plots. I tried with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) but it looks like it's not able to open the csv format created with NetLogo:

"export-plots data (NetLogo 5.0.5)"

^

"C:\results\interface.csv", line 1: invalid command

How can I open csv plots with an external reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two complicating factors about NetLogo's plot export format. First, there's a three line header at the beginning (plus an empty line after) that just gives information about the model and when the data was generated. Next, there's data about the model settings, the plot state (pen colors and such). Finally, there's the data itself, which itself is somewhat complicated by the fact that you can have multiple pens per plot. So I'm not surprised gnuplot couldn't read it as is.

The table's are quite easy to use in GUI spreadsheet application, like Excel, LibreOffice's Calc, or Gnumeric. You can just select the data you want and generate the plots.

To do this at the command line, I'm afraid you might have to write a script to read it in. This should be pretty easy in something like Python or R. Just skip the metadata lines, and use a CSV parser to read in the rest.

You might also try using [BehaviorSpace](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html) to generate the data, but make sure to use the table output. It let's you generate the data from many runs at once, and the format is a little more consistent. There are still 6 lines of metadata at the top, but you can just delete that. I believe this is more the standard practice in NetLogo.

Comment: Maybe just deleting the header lines at the top would be enough to make it work with gnuplot?

Comment: Thanks, i used your idea to import data into Excel. Then manually i can create the plots. It's gonna be a little time consuming but it's working great! I tried to play with headers and import files into gnuplot but without results.