# How to extract plots from Netlogo?

Tags: plot, netlogo

I have to write a report about a model that I have built using Netlogo. I have made many plots of model's variables and I'd like to extract them and put them in my report to show how these variables vary upon the time. These variables represent what the change of some parameters imply. So, I'd like to obtain a better plot than netlogo's one, because netlogo's plots haven't got enumerated axis and I'd like plots with enumerated axis.

It would be amazing to put the plot in a word document or in a power point document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the NetLogo dictionary entry for `export-all-plots`. The easiest way to access this is the menu File > Export > Export All Plots ... and then choose a folder/directory to store the file and a file name. You will then get a file in csv format that you can open in your graphing package (eg R, Excel).

Comment: further info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985793/export-plots-with-netlogo